# Will Apple reject an app with "background fetch" which is used to upload a photos

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Looks like this is the right place to ask.

Basically I'm gonna to build an app which, while suspended periodically uploads photos to server (just like Google Photos uploads new photos to their backend while the app is in background).

I'm thinking of using Background Fetch to get notified of a moment to check if sync is required and to upload any photos if so.

The question is will apple reject the app?

My concern here is that according to [the specs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23) Background Fetch is intended to **fetch** **small** amount of data from the network while I'm gonna to use it like in the opposite direction - to **upload** **relatively big** amount of data.

Probably someone had similar experience.

It's like a different question, however if this approach doesn't work, could anyone bring the light on what an appropriate solution could be? Google got approved with their photos anyway so there should be a way (yes, I'm not Google but hopefully there is a solution for ordinary developer as well).

Answer (score 2):

Background Fetch only allows you to download data and the process exit if the transfer time is superior to 30 seconds. There are limited things you can do while the app is in Background mode : [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

If you want to upload your photos in the background you'll need to use background transfer service, but once the task is finished the app will not upload more data. This tutorial explains how to download a file without the application in the foreground but you can use the same logic to send data : [iOS 7 SDK: Background Transfer Service](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service--mobile-20595)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I'm aware of time interval the app has to process the notification and actually transfer service is what I intended to use to upload photos. Thanks for mentioning it anyway. The question is will apple review team be ok with this way of using "Background Fetch" feature?

Comment: No one can tell you what their exact response will be but theoretically if the process is under 30 sec it should be fine.

Comment: Agree that it's hard to predict the exact response and even if someone passed the review once there is no 100% guarantee that the second time their response will be the same. However I believe there is more or less predictable way the review team will behave in the case describe in the question. I just think it worth to ask before building MVP and being rejected because of "misled guidelines". Thanks anyway for your time.